# Text control not showing in QT ApplicationWindow

Tags: qt, qml

I have installed Qt 5.12.0 and created QtQuick empty application. I main.qml added below code

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Text {    
        text: "Qt Quick"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}
```

Text control is not showing while running the application

Comment: The code is correct, it's working

Comment: Any other reason like incorrect configuration or settings?

Comment: I run it as is from your post

Comment: Try changing the color of the text to see if it is somehow hidden on the window's background color. That could be caused by theming issues on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set up your .pro file and main.cpp according to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html

The application's .pro project file must specify the declarative module for the QT variable. For example:

```
TEMPLATE += app
QT += quick
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Just a side-note; the framework you're using is called Qt, not QT.